# Understanding Materialized View Refresh Group Interval

Tags: oracle

I am creating a Materialized View Refresh Group in our Oracle 12c database and I would like for the materialized views to be refresh every Monday (after 1700 would be best).  On this page: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14227/rarrefreshpac.htm#i94210, the interval section says: 
"

```
Function used to calculate the next time to refresh the materialized views in the group. This field is used with the next_date value.

For example, if you specify NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE+1, "MONDAY") as your interval, and if your next_date evaluates to Monday, then Oracle refreshes the materialized views every Monday. This interval is evaluated immediately before the refresh. Thus, you should select an interval that is greater than the time it takes to perform a refresh.
```

"

So that would mean that the next day after today's date that is Monday would be the next refresh date and this would be calculated during each refresh, correct?

If so, then I believe I understand that concept; however, when I try to apply the exact same syntax that Oracle provided I get an error.  This is what I tried (mv names modified):

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_REFRESH.MAKE(name => 'mv_refresh_group',
 list => 'first_mv
        , second_mv
        , third_mv
        , fourth_mv',
 next_date => sysdate,
 interval => next_day(sysdate+ 1, "MONDAY")) ;
END;
```

I get an error stating that the identifier "MONDAY" must be declared.  I believe that is caused by using double quotes so I changed it to single quotes, but now I get this error:

```
ORA-23319: parameter value "23-DEC-19" is not appropriate
```

So then I searched for answers to ORA-23319 and saw that it is caused by passing a date where a string is expected in an interval argument.  I believe this is caused by sysdate + 1.  So then I tried to put quotes around it, like I did with Monday but I get an error:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_REFRESH.MAKE(name => 'mv_refresh_group',
 list => 'first_mv
        , second_mv
        , third_mv
        , fourth_mv',
 next_date => sysdate,
 interval => next_day('sysdate+ 1', 'MONDAY')) ;
END;



PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(sysdate+ 1" when expecting one of the following:


ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

I'm not sure how to handle these errors.  I believe I am using the exact syntax provided by Oracle but it is not working correctly.  Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.  Also, if anyone can provide guidance on how to specify a certain time very MOnday that would be great; however, the most important thing is that I can understand how to resolve this error.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you also add the code after you made the changes so we can check why are you receiving the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_REFRESH.MAKE(name => 'mv_refresh_group',
 list => 'first_mv
        , second_mv
        , third_mv
        , fourth_mv',
 next_date => sysdate,
 interval => 'next_day(sysdate+ 1, ''MONDAY'')') ;
END;
```

`interval` is a string parameter containing a SQL expression that evaluates to a date.  As it is a string, you must enclose the entire thing in single quotes (as per all Oracle strings).  The string-literal within the expression (i.e., 'MONDAY') must have its single quotes escaped as two single quotes (i.e., `''MONDAY''`, not `"MONDAY"`).

Comment: Thank you very much!  This worked perfectly.  That explanation makes sense.  I see where I kept messing up.  I wasn't aware that you could pass an entire function call as a string but I guess it stores that and then executes it during each refresh to determine the next refresh date.